# Determine with proof if the following integral converges

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Determine if the following integral converge.
$$\int^\infty_2 \ln\left(\sec\left(\pi\over x\right)\right)\ dx$$

I have a function to compare the above over the interval [2, 3], but am struggling to find one that will compare nicely over [3, $\infty$]. $1\over x^{1.1}$ can be used to show that it does converge using comparison, but is having trouble showing the function is greater than the one above over [3, $\infty$]. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $z=0$ we have the expansion
$$\sec z=1+\frac{z^2}{2}+O\left(z^3\right)$$
so as $z\to 0$
$$\log\sec z \sim \log \left(1+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\sim \frac{z^2}{2}$$
thus as $x\to\infty$
$$\log\sec\frac{\pi}{x}\sim \frac{\pi ^2}{2 x^2}$$
therefore for the comparison test the integral converges at $+\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sec(x)\approx1+\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)...$$
$$\sec\left(\frac\pi x\right)=1+\frac{k_1}{x^2}+O(x^{-4})$$
now we know that:
$$\ln(x)\approx x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$$
so for large $x$ we can say that:
$$\ln\left[\sec\left(\frac\pi x\right)\right]\approx\frac{k_1}{x^2}+O(x^{-4})$$
and then by comparison test we know that $1/x^2$ integral converges